# Asynchronous GET requests for an unknown # of URLs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping

What's an optimal solution for making an unknown number of asynchronous GET requests?

For example, you have the following url, 'http://www.example.org/', and you'd like to make a set of asynchronous requests to the following paths:

```
[
    'http://www.example.org/A-1.html',
    'http://www.example.org/A-2.html',
    'http://www.example.org/A-3.html',
    '...',
    'http://www.example.org/B-1.html'
    'http://www.example.org/B-2.html'
    '...'
]
```

and so forth. If, say, '...C-12.html' does not exist, you get an invalid response header code. How would you go about making a set of parallel requests?

Comment: What do you want to do when you get an error on one of the requests?  Stop all other requests?  Ignore that one error and keep going?  Two tools that could help you are are promises and the Async library for node.js.

Comment: To make get requests in parallel use https://www.npmjs.com/package/async parallel method.

Comment: Yes, I've used both of those libraries before, but was curious to see an optimal and elegant solution for this.

I'd like the requests for that specific iterator to stop; i.e. A-1, A-2, A-3, and once it reaches say A-20 (undefined) that set of requests stop, however, B-Z are still in process.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var request=require('request');
    var vrlList = [
        'http://www.example.org/A-1.html',
        'http://www.example.org/A-2.html',
        'http://www.example.org/A-3.html',
        '...',
        'http://www.example.org/B-1.html'
        'http://www.example.org/B-2.html'
        '...'
    ];
    var outPutData = [];
    forEach(function(url,index){


  request({ method: 'GET', uri: url }, function (error, response, body) { 
       outPutData.push({"url":url,data:body});
    }).on('data', function(data) {

    }).on('error', function(err) {
          console.log(err)
    }).on('response', function(response) { 
       response.on('data', function(data) { 
       })
   })
```

});

Comment: This is a clean solution if you know the number of requests ahead of time, however, in this scenario,  you do not know how deep each page goes for any given subset.

Answer (score 0):

I think its an algorithmic task.

Say you have A-Z (26 rows to be processed).
Also you might implement say only 15 threads in parallel.

So you load the first 15 rows in the `process` array: `A-O`;
Then you start multi-threaded process upon the `process`. 
When, say, `B-56` is not defined (undefined), you just throw exception and in the `process` array you load next row `P` while excluding row `B`.

This way you will iterate over all the remaining rows `P-Z`.

Comment: Yeah, that's along the same type of approach I was thinking about... Would love to see an elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: @FarhadGhayour, SO is not a kitchen to cook for you ("*would love to see an elegant solution for this problem*")! What if you get deeper into any of languages and make at least a project scatch for this task?

Comment: I'll post up the solution for others to view and, hopefully, learn or improve upon.

The simpler approach was extending the functionality with util.inherits(CONSTRUCTOR, EventEmitter) and then using the simple pub/sub approach for the parallel requests, but perhaps a more robust solution would be to use Promises or something like Highland.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with using the JQuery deferred object.

```js
function getUrls(urls, callback) {
  var result,
    i = 0;
  var g = $.Deferred()
    .done(callback);
  urls.forEach(function(u, i) {
    $.getJSON(u, function(data) {
      // Do whatever processing you need to do here
      if (++i === dcnames.length) {
        g.resolve(result) // invoke the callback with the result
      }
    })
  })
}
```

The Deferred object waits to resolve until the last call is made. Although forEach is a syncronous (blocking) process, since the getJSONs themselves are async, the loop will run through all of the requests in parallel, and wait to resolve until they are all done.